# Rearrange JSON data in a specific way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I have a JSON data set similar to what's below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Concert 1",
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "name": "Woolworths",
        "location": "Mildura"
      },
      {
        "name": "Coles",
        "location": "Melbourne"
      },
      {
        "name": "Metricon",
        "location": "Wagga Wagga"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Concert 2",
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "name": "Metricon",
        "location": "Albert Park"
      },
      {
        "name": "Woolworths",
        "location": "Melbourne"
      },
      {
        "name": "ALDI",
        "location": "Bendigo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Concert 3",
    "sponsors": [
      {
        "name": "Holcim",
        "location": "Bendigo"
      },
      {
        "name": "Westpac",
        "location": "Melbourne"
      },
      {
        "name": "Coles",
        "location": "Mildura"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I would like to display this JSON output in the following format on a webpage:

```
Location X
   Sponsor X
      Concert 1
      Concert 2
      -------
   Sponsor Y
      Concert 1
Location Y
   Sponsor Y
      Concert 1
      Concert 2
      ------
   --------
```

Basically, what I have to display the Location at the top level and the other elements as children elements on that, turn the JSON dataset upside down in other words.

So far I have tried looping through the JSON file using VueJS computed properties but still no luck. Could someone please show me how I can resolve this?

I'm sorry if I haven't used the proper technical terms here, because I'm not sure what do we call when we display something like this.

Comment: please post the JS code you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how to convert the data:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Concert 1",
    "sponsors": [
      {"name": "Woolworths","location": "Melbourne"},
      {"name": "Coles","location": "Melbourne"},
      {"name": "Metricon","location": "Wagga Wagga"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Concert 2",
    "sponsors": [
      {"name": "Metricon","location": "Albert Park"},
      {"name": "Woolworths","location": "Melbourne"},
      {"name": "ALDI","location": "Bendigo"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Concert 3",
    "sponsors": [
      {"name": "Holcim","location": "Bendigo"},
      {"name": "Westpac","location": "Melbourne"},
      {"name": "Coles","location": "Mildura"}
    ]
  }
];

const byLocation = data.reduce((r, con) => (con.sponsors.forEach(sp => {
  if (!r[sp.location]) r[sp.location] = {};
  if (!r[sp.location][sp.name]) r[sp.location][sp.name] = [];
  r[sp.location][sp.name].push(con.name);
}), r), {});

console.log(byLocation);
```

**To explain the above:**

To convert the initial `data` **Array** of concerts

```js
[
  concert,
  concert,
  // ...
]
```

**into an Object** - where all the property names (locations) are unique

```js
{
  "location name 1": {},
  "location name 2": {},
  // ...
}
```

the first idea is to use [`Array.prototype.reduce()` <sup><sub>*MDN*</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const byLocation = data.reduce((resultObject, concert) => {
  // Insert concert data into resultObject here
  return resultObject; // Return the Object for the next iteration
}, {}); // << {} is the resultObject
```

a bit of renaming for shortness, and by using **Arrow function's Implicit Return** (no wrapping curly braces) we can convert/shorten the above to:

```js
const byLocation = data.reduce((r, con) => (/*Insert con data into r*/, r), {});
```

So `con` is the iterating Concert, and `r` is the Resulting final Object we need to build.
Let's populate the `r` object by `forEach`-ing the `con.sponsors` Array

```js
  con.sponsors.forEach(sp => { // sp is the iterating Sponsor
    // If r["location name"] does not exists, create it as empty object
    if (!r[sp.location]) r[sp.location] = {};
    // If r["location name"]["Sponsor name"] does not exists, create it
    // as an empty array
    if (!r[sp.location][sp.name]) r[sp.location][sp.name] = [];
    // Finally push the Concert name into that array.
    r[sp.location][sp.name].push(con.name);
  })
```

If the concept is too *advanced*, it can also be written like this:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Concert 1",
    "sponsors": [
      {"name": "Woolworths","location": "Melbourne"},
      {"name": "Coles","location": "Melbourne"},
      {"name": "Metricon","location": "Wagga Wagga"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Concert 2",
    "sponsors": [
      {"name": "Metricon","location": "Albert Park"},
      {"name": "Woolworths","location": "Melbourne"},
      {"name": "ALDI","location": "Bendigo"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Concert 3",
    "sponsors": [
      {"name": "Holcim","location": "Bendigo"},
      {"name": "Westpac","location": "Melbourne"},
      {"name": "Coles","location": "Mildura"}
    ]
  }
];

const byLocation = {}; // The resulting object of unique Locations

data.forEach((concert) => {

  const sponsors = concert.sponsors;
  
  sponsors.forEach((sponsor) => {
  
    if (!byLocation.hasOwnProperty(sponsor.location)) {
        byLocation[sponsor.location] = {};
    }
    
    if (!byLocation[sponsor.location].hasOwnProperty(sponsor.name)) {
        byLocation[sponsor.location][sponsor.name] = [];
    }
    
    byLocation[sponsor.location][sponsor.name].push(concert.name);
  });
  
});

console.log(byLocation);
```

---

To display the data inside a `<ul id="list"></ul>`, in JavaScript:

```js
const html = Object.entries(byLocation).reduce((h, [location, ob]) => {
  h += `<li>${location}<ul>`;
  Object.entries(ob).forEach(([sponsor, concerts]) => {
    h += `<li>${sponsor}
            <ul>
              <li>${concerts.join('</li><li>')}</li>
            </ul>
          </li>`;
  }); 
  h += `</ul></li>`;
  return h
}, ''); 

document.querySelector('#list').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

Comment: Hey Roko, thank you very much for your answer, this saved me. Would it be too much if I ask you to explain the code you've written ?. This is all good working like a charm but I would like to understand what exactly you have done here, specially the use of `reduce()`. That would be great if you can put some comments, it will help me and whoever come next looking for something like this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dynamdilshan Here's the syntax for a reduce:
`array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue)`.
So, what Roko is doing there is:
`r`: "total" of the reduce, this means, the value that will be returned at the end.
`con`: the current concert. He then loops through the sponsor of each concert, and create an entry on the `r` object if one doesn't exists already, and the same with the sponsor name.
Finally, `initialValue` is the value of `r` in the first iteration of the `reduce` function, an empty object in this case (`{}`).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @tintef  I really appreciate your help! I also added some explanation.

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan, I'm sorry if I'm taking this back and forth. I have one last question with this solution. If I want to sort all these entries alphabetically, how would I do that ?. Could you please point me to the correct direction ?.

Comment: @Dynamdilshan please Ask a **New Question** if there's something outside of the scope of this one.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is:

- pass your json data to your vue in the data object
- add a computed property 'formattedData', and provide a function that will format the json data in a format you need.
- Use this computed property in the template to render the data.

I will give a rough outline of what you can do:

```
var concertData = [
    {
        "name": "Concert 1",
        "sponsors": [
            {
                "name": "Woolworths",
                "location": "Mildura"
            },
            {
                "name": "Coles",
                "location": "Melbourne"
            },
            {
                "name": "Metricon",
                "location": "Wagga Wagga"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Concert 2",
        "sponsors": [
            {
                "name": "Metricon",
                "location": "Albert Park"
            },
            {
                "name": "Woolworths",
                "location": "Melbourne"
            },
            {
                "name": "ALDI",
                "location": "Bendigo"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Concert 3",
        "sponsors": [
            {
                "name": "Holcim",
                "location": "Bendigo"
            },
            {
                "name": "Westpac",
                "location": "Melbourne"
            },
            {
                "name": "Coles",
                "location": "Mildura"
            }
        ]
    }
];

new Vue({
  data: {
    concerts: concertData // pass your concert json here
  },
    computed: {
        formattedData: function () {
            var formattedData = new Map();
            this.concerts.forEach(function (item) {
                item.sponsors.forEach(function (sponsor) {
                    if (!formattedData.has(sponsor.location)) {
                        formattedData.set(sponsor.location, new Map());
                    }

                    if (!formattedData.get(sponsor.location).has(sponsor.name)) {
                        formattedData.get(sponsor.location).set(sponsor.name, []);
                    }

                    formattedData.get(sponsor.location).get(sponsor.name).push(item.name);
                })
            });

            return formattedData;
        }
    },
    render: function(h) {
        // loop over this.formattedData to paint the display
    }

}).$mount("#app");
```